# upgrading from .net 4.0 to 4.5 breaks ckeditor .net

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor.net

CKeditor.net was workin gfine on .net framework 4.0 but it breaks after ugrading to 4.5 framework. on ckEditor page theres only mentioned that .net 2.0+ is supported.

Could not load file or assembly 'CKEditor.NET' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

CK editor assembly registeration is causing error

How to get CKeditor working on 4.5 framework?

Comment: please rovider more details about the error messages, while it does not work as well as CKEditor link

Comment: Please check your project references properties CKEditor.NET Local Copy property=true.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry ... test site was missing bin files and public site Master had an error (sometimes team updates make things confusing)

for information - I copied bins to test site and fixed public site master prove that CKEditor .net is working correctly on .net 4.5 framework.